# How to audit an asp.net/SQL Server user

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am building a very simple asp.net application that will have a SQL Server 2008 backend.

Some users will be entering data and storing in the database and some users will be viewing data.

The SQL Server 2008 is working with Windows authentication for every user; however, I am unable to get ASP.NET working with Windows authentication yet. Is there a simple way to allow windows authentication with ASP.NET? I found a very convoluted way, but I don't like it.

I will need to audit every action that the users perform.

Should I audit the users at the application level or at the SQL Server level?

Are there already built in methods to do this? If so, how?

Comment: Is there a few specific things that seem convoluted to you, so we can help you better? Windows Authentication has always been straightforward for me.

Comment: @rib. different sections of the asp.net website need to be viewed by different people.

Comment: how would i allow default.aspx to everyone but block page.aspx from only certain users?>

Comment: Read [SQL Server 2008 Auditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to get started on auditing at the SQL Server level

Comment: @marc what do u think of this solution? http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/27/adding-simple-trigger-based-auditing-to-your-sql-server-database.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this from the application if it is significant HOW people accessed the data as much as the WHO, but that's quite different from rlb.usa's answer. In my past jobs, it's often been as important to know which application the person changed data from as when/who.  If it's primarily for application issues, log4net is a good option.

Comment: how would i allow default.aspx to everyone but block page.aspx from only certain users?

Comment: You can do this with permissions, either application wide or per-page. See here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

Answer (score 3):

On the contrary, I have always found Windows Authentication to be quite easy to set up and relatively painless. Here's some guides:

- [Setting up](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-vb)
- [More Setting up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)

I didn't realize that you could audit what users did at the ASP.NET level. My answer would  be to use SQL Server for this one. You'd need to log:

- timestamps and user name for every action
- do you need to log workstation or location where the actions were performed?
- can users go to mul
- if multiple locations use this application, consider storing UTC time only
- all actions, even deletes, which mean that delete's only get "hidden" from the user, but never erased from the database. Same for edits, the old record should never be changed or taken out of the database.

Your best bet here is to talk to your boss about this one. Auditors can have very specific needs, and you definitely don't want to forget anything. Every situation is different, so be sure to sit down and double check all your requirements and specifications.

Comment: @rub. thanks so much,. how would i audit on the database level?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no magic procedure that does it all for you. You'd have to write it all yourself. Be sure to spend some extra time in the planning phase.

Comment: @rub also be aware that trusted connections from IIS to SQL Server won't be an option.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. Here is example on Win auth on asp.net app:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/07/12/Recipe_3A00_-Enabling-Windows-Authentication-within-an-Intranet-ASP.NET-Web-application.aspx

1. I suggest you implement a log framework like log4net to log your application. It's simple and easy to use  http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html

Comment: thank you very much - how would i allow default.aspx to everyone but block page.aspx from only certain users?

Comment: you can do it with roles. Control access to different pages with roles. Here is a very good tutorial on membership and role providers in asp.net http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx. If you are happy with my answer please accept it as solution